# How can I tell JWrapper to only build the 64-bit version of app on Mac?

Tags: jwrapper

I want to build a 32-bit and 64-bit application for Windows and Linux, but only a 64-bit application for Mac,

Currently my app .xml file looks like this:

```
    <Windows64JRE>JRE-1.7/win32/jre1.7.0_05</Windows64JRE>
    <Windows32JRE>JRE-1.7/win32/jre1.7.0_05</Windows32JRE>
    <Linux64JRE>JRE-1.7/linuxx64/jre1.7.0_13</Linux64JRE>
    <Linux32JRE>JRE-1.7/linux/jre1.7.0_13</Linux32JRE>
    <Mac64JRE>JRE-1.7/macos64/jre1.7.0_45.jre</Mac64JRE>
```

Although I have not specified a Mac32JRE, a dmg file is always created (MYAPP-macos32-offline.dmg)  How can I tell JWrapper to only build the 64-bit version for Mac?

Answer (score 2):

You can skip platforms by adding any of these tags:

```
<SkipMacOS>true</SkipMacOS>

<SkipWindows>true</SkipWindows>

<SkipLinux>true</SkipLinux>
```

but you can't skip architectures for a platform.  The mac-32 build is for earlier versions of OSX and doesn't include a JRE since there isn't a redistributable JRE for those versions of MacOS.  Instead it relies on the system Java and will request that it is installed if necessary. As time goes on though its less relevant since mac users tend to upgrade to later versions frequently.

You can pick and choose what final executables you use though and leave the rest.  The first time the build runs it will be quite slow as the JREs have to be packed but subsequent builds should be fast (30s on a decent laptop) and the extra architecture for a particular platform won't add very much to the overall build time.